# How can I add “X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff” in Global.asax.cs to prevent mime sniff

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security

I have modified the web.config as to prevent the mime sniff.

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
         <customHeaders>
            <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
         </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

but code scan tool still told me that global.asax.cs has the vulnerabilities

```
Application_BeginRequest is either empty or does not include a function call to set the X-Content-Type-Options to nosniff or attempts to remove that header.
```

So how to set X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff in Global.asax.cs ?

Comment: What version of IIS using ?

Comment: @VIGNESHARUNACHALAM  we don't want to handle the problem in IIS. because sometimes the code is not deployed in IIS.... we want to handle directly in code level

Comment: I hope this is use full...

Comment: IIS version is important because if it's < v7 the settings need to go in the system.web section rather than the system.webServer.

Answer (score 6):

**Using  in Web.Config**

To add these headers, go to the `<customHeaders>` node previously added and add those headers inside the `<customHeaders>` node.

```
<httpprotocol> 
 <customheaders> 
    <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff "/>
 </customheaders> 
</httpprotocol>
```

**Using global.asax.cs**

```
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(Object source, EventArgs e) {
   HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
}
```

Comment: @allencharp for more details,http://www.insiderattack.net/2014/04/configuring-secure-iis-response-headers.html & https://vulncat.hpefod.com/en/detail?id=desc.structural.dotnet.html5_mime_sniffing

Comment: Hi  what's the difference of the two ways... should I implement both ways on the code or just one of them ?

Comment: If you have it in the web.config, you can change it later, at runtime, without having to recompile and redeploy your app.

Comment: If you define your headers in code (in the global.asax.cs) they're part of your application and cannot be changed - unless you change your code and re-deploy your application. Having them in the web.config allows you to change these values just by simply editing the web.config - no code changes needed, no redeployment needed etc.